# Dragging controls during runtime - how to lock controls

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to Drag controls around during runtime.

The code below is an example I found on the web that does exactly what I need it to do. The article dated back to 2009 and was rather dead so I couldn't ask any questions.
The problem with this code is that every control on the Form can be moved around. Even when locking certain controls.

Is there a way to prevent certain controls from being moved?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dragging As Boolean
    Dim startX As Integer
    Dim startY As Integer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 
        ''NorthwindDataSet.Employees' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.EmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.NorthwindDataSet.Employees)
        For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
            AddHandler Control.MouseDown, AddressOf startDrag
            AddHandler Control.MouseMove, AddressOf whileDragging
            AddHandler Control.MouseUp, AddressOf endDrag
        Next
        For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
            For Each item In My.Settings.controlLocations
                If Split(item, "!")(0) = Control.Name Then
                    Control.Location = New Point(Split(item, "!")(1), _
                        Split(item, "!")(2))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub startDrag(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        dragging = True
        startX = e.X
        startY = e.Y
    End Sub
    Private Sub whileDragging(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If dragging = True Then
            sender.Location = New Point(sender.Location.X + _
        e.X - startX, sender.Location.Y + e.Y - startY)
            Me.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub endDrag(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        dragging = False
        My.Settings.controlLocations.Clear()
        For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
            My.Settings.controlLocations.Add(Control.Name & "!" _
        & Control.Location.X & "!" & Control.Location.Y)
        Next
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The 3 subs do all the work, and there is a blank My.Settings named controlLocations that stores the locations.

**EDIT 1**
Example:

```
For Each label1 As Control In Me.Controls
            AddHandler label1.MouseDown, AddressOf startDrag
            AddHandler label1.MouseMove, AddressOf whileDragging
            AddHandler label1.MouseUp, AddressOf endDrag
        Next
        For Each label1 As Control In Me.Controls
            For Each item In My.Settings.controlLocations
                If Split(item, "!")(0) = label1.Name Then
                    label1.Location = New Point(Split(item, "!")(1), Split(item, "!")(2))
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: you are explicitly hooking up every control: `For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls`  just do the ones you want

Comment: I added an example to the question. Should I change it to something like that?

Comment: thats going to do the exact same thing - all you did was change the iteration variable.  I have no idea what controls you want to exempt or include, as the question says is `certain controls`.  You could use the designer to put "LOCK" in the tag property then skip those in your loop

Comment: I'm a bit stuck now as I have never worked with anything like this before. Let's say I want all the Labels to be locked. Could you give an example in code if you have the time?

Comment: just add an if:  `If TypeOf ctl Is Label = False Then...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Below is the code that will allow the user to move around controls (only the ones they wish to be movable) in a windows form. Just add the handlers for each control behind the subs.

```
        Dim startx As Integer
        Dim starty As Integer
        Dim endy As Integer
        Dim endx As Integer
        Dim finalx As Integer
        Dim finaly As Integer
        Dim mdown As Boolean
        Dim valx As Boolean
        Dim valy As Boolean

        Private Sub Main_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        End Sub

        Private Sub MuisDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
            startx = MousePosition.X
            starty = MousePosition.Y
            mdown = True
            valx = False
            valy = False
        End Sub

        Private Sub MuisUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
            mdown = False
            valx = False
            valy = False
        End Sub

        Private Sub MuisMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
            If mdown = True Then
                endx = (MousePosition.X - Me.Left)
                endy = (MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)

                If valy = False Then
                    starty = endy - sender.top
                    valy = True
                End If
                If valx = False Then
                    startx = endx - sender.left
                    valx = True
                End If
                sender.left = endx - startx
                sender.top = endy - starty
            End If
        End Sub
```

**Example Label1 + PictureBox1**

```
Private Sub MuisDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseDown, PictureBox1.MouseDown

Private Sub MuisUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseUp, PictureBox1.MouseUp

Private Sub MuisMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseMove, PictureBox1.MouseMove
```